# Execute SQL query in C# dot net for Rule engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, rule-engine

I building app like Rule Engine(Background Job) it will fetch SQL query(formed by user via UI) from table. And then I need to run these query to fetch the data from DB.

**Query(Rules) Table:**
[image]

I created stored procedure which fetch sql query and it will returns filtered records to me.

But is there any other way to achieve the same in Dot Net/C# where I can pull query and table records and then I will execute the sql query in my C# code to filter the records.

User is having 1K query(rules) in table and i need to execute all rules one by one to get the matching records. So Im trying to avoid executing the query 1k times in DB.

Any advice/guide will really helpful

Thanks
Karthisena

Comment: I'm sorry if I've misunderstood you, but why doesn't you just query the data you need with an where statement instead? 
and yes its possible with c# with an namespace like SQLClient as an example.

Comment: I agree. Don't pull large amounts of data into your UI. That's what your database is for? All you will do is slow your application down if you start manipulating large datasets in code. 1K hits on the database is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Hi Thanks and assume below scenario  I have 1000K records in a medical claim table and 1k rules(Query) .Now i need to find out a single  claim record will satisfy how many rules(Query) out of 1k rules. So in this case i need to execute 1000k queries . So im trying to avoid this scenario because its purely background job for analytics purpose. Any Idea ?  Thanks